# Why Control Busy Indicator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sapui5, busyindicator

My purpose is to show [Control Busy Indicator](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.ControlBusyIndicator/preview) when I send a data to [my oModel create function](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#create).  But I can't see it maybe because of oModel sync issues. It should appear before oModel is called and disappear when fnSuccess function works. I tried to use sync create function like :

```
var fnSuccess = function(oData, oResponse) {
    oVbox.setBusy(false);
};
oVbox.setBusy(true);
oModel.create("sPath", serviceData, null, fnSuccess, fnError, true);
```

but still I can't see control busy indicator. Also I have same problem with [Busy Indicator](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.BusyIndicator/samples). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try, oVbox.setBusyIndicatorDelay(0);
then oVBox.setbusy(true);

if that does not work, try to add a small delay between setBusy and calling the create method. (with setTimeout)

Comment: thank you I changed the code little bit but I will try and I guess setTimeout will work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary that it will come always. Basically It depends upon the execution time of your code.

Comment: but sending data and receiving it's parameter takes long time and I guess it should come.

Comment: If your code is going smoothly then why do you want this. It is used for code which takes a lot of processing time(In javascript there is only one thread) but in your case it is working fine.

Comment: But I need to show my clients this busy indicator as they have to see this to know that the process is working on the background. My codes take a ot of time and my clients need to see this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help understand the problem a little more can you set the value of .setBusy to true in the success function.
This will help diagnose your problem as it could be to do with the speed of the load.

e.g.

```
var fnSuccess = function(oData, oResponse) {
    oVbox.setBusy(true);
};
```

Comment: yes @Bernard I am able to set and I can see the Control Busy Indicator after I set.